# adding items in an array in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, addition, mips

I'm writing in Assembly on a Mac book and I'm having a problem adding items in an array.

I need to get the average of the items in the array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

A few of the comments might say 5 but I've switched it to take in 10 numbers and just didn't change them yet. I think it has something to do with the way I'm loading the numbers from the array but I'm not sure.

```
.text
    .globl main
main:

la $t0, array    # load address of array into $t0
li $t1, 10        # size of array is 5 (0 - 4)
li $t3, 0        # initialize counter to zero
li $t6, 0

#Populate the array 

while:  
la $a0, intPrompt        #prompt for integer
li $v0,4                 #a0 = address of string
syscall                  #v0 = 4, indicates display a String

li $v0,5                 # enter input -> v0
syscall                  # 5 is sys call for read int

sw $v0, ($t0)

add $t0,$t0,4            # move pointer ahead to next array element
add $t3,$t3,1            # increment counter


blt $t3,$t1,while        # branch to while if counter < size of array


# End While to populate the array 
wend: 

la $a0,title        # Display "Array: "
li $v0,4            # a0 = address of message
    syscall

# Loop to print array values

li $t0, 0           # initilize array index value back to 0
li $t3, 0           # initial size counter back to zero
la $t0, array       # load address of array back into $t0

startPrint:

lw $t2,($t0)        # load word a[i] into temp (t2)
move $a0, $t2       # move a[i] to a0 for display
li $v0,1            # display a[i]
syscall

la $a0,comma        # Display ", "
li $v0,4            # a0 = address of message
syscall             # v0 = 4 which indicates display a string

add $t0,$t0,4       # move pointer ahead to next array element 
add $t3, $t3, 1     #increment counter

blt $t3,$t1,startPrint     # branch to startPrint if counter < size of array

endPrint:     # End loop to print array values

startAdd:

lw $t2,($t0)
move $a0,$t2

add $t6, $t6, $t0

add $t0, $t0,4
add $t3, $t3, 1

blt $t3, $t1,startAdd

endAdd:


move $a0, $t6
li $v0, 1
syscall

la $a0,crlf         # Display "cr/lf"
li $v0,4            # a0 = address of message
syscall             # v0 = 4 which indicates display a string

li $v0,10           # End Of Program
syscall

.data

intPrompt:  .asciiz   "Enter an Integer: "   # hold the prompt message for each int in the array  
title:      .asciiz   "\nArray: "
crlf:       .asciiz   "\n"
comma:      .asciiz   ", "

array:      .word 40  # 5 words
```

Comment: Please expand your description of what happens now: "just didn't change them yet"? What didn't? Where didn't it?

Comment: I didn't change the comments, that's all. Some of them say "sets array to 5" but it's really 10, that's it.

The issue is adding items in the array.

Comment: So the exact same code works correctly with the value `5`?

Comment: Yes, I just need to figure out how to add the contents of the array.